# how do I write a clojure factory function with an incrementing id?

Tags: clojure

I'd like to write something like this (not working):

```
(defn new-connection []
  (let [c (atom 0)]
    {:id #(swap! c inc)
    :writebuf (ByteBuffer/allocate 8096)
    :readbuf (ByteBuffer/allocate 8096)}))
```

Such that I can get incrementally id'd maps with (new-connection), Do I need to define the counter separately or is there a way to inline it with this function?

Comment: Depends, how much value do you place on referential transparency?

Comment: does that refer to mobyte's comment in his edit below, about 'hiding' the counter?

Comment: Can you expect referential transparency when object's counting is involved? I doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closure` mechanism to "inline" counter:

```
(let [c (atom 0)]
  (defn new-connection []
    {:id (swap! c inc)
     :writebuf :ByteBuffer
     :readbuf :ByteBuffer})
  (defn get-counter []
    @c))

(get-counter)
=> 0

(new-connection)
=> {:id 1, :writebuf :ByteBuffer, :readbuf :ByteBuffer}

(new-connection)
=> {:id 2, :writebuf :ByteBuffer, :readbuf :ByteBuffer}

(get-counter)
=> 2
```

Or if you need to control counter start value:

```
(defn create-connection-fn [init-counter-value]
  (let [c (atom init-counter-value)]
    (fn []
      {:id (swap! c inc)
       :writebuf :ByteBuffer
       :readbuf :ByteBuffer})))

(def new-connection (create-connection-fn 10))

(new-connection)
=> {:id 11, :writebuf :ByteBuffer, :readbuf :ByteBuffer}

(new-connection)
=> {:id 12, :writebuf :ByteBuffer, :readbuf :ByteBuffer}
```

**Edit.** I suggest you to define the counter as separated variable if there is no reason to "hide" it.

Comment: thank you for the answer. One question, I have read it's not a good idea to define vars within functions (like (defn ...(def ..)) ). Does this hold for defining functions within a let like the above?

Comment: @georgek No. `let` over `defn` is not a common clojure construct (people seem to dislike it, although I like it myself), but there's nothing conceptually wrong with it. Conversely, def within def is really problematic.

Comment: When a var is outside a function (and perhaps passed to it explicitly) it's much easier to control the behavior of the function. It's then easier to use anything that can count and return next value. In let-over-def(n) case it's just `atom`. More important reason against using let-over-def is that it's harder to introduce new functions to operate on the counter - they'll have to become a part of the `let` scope. Since we use functions to compose functions (not namespaces) my gut feelings tell me to define counters as vars outside functions.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Thanks for your comment. Yes, you're right. I have already mentioned this in my edit. BTW the whole answer was about how to "inline" counter with the function but not about why you should do it )

Comment: Isn't your initial (main) answer more an encouragement than a discouragement now? :-)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski It's the answer to particular question and nothing else. It's unbiased )

Comment: @mobyte but still there's an answer and people might follow the path. I think it might cause more harm than be helpful. We'll see soon if more similar questions show up.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general problem of having a counter. If you decompose things a bit you will find that you need three things: 1) Something to create new counter 2) A connection counter 3) The new connection function which accepts the id as param rather than calling the counter itself as that makes this function more general.

```
(defn new-counter []
  (partial apply swap! (atom 0) inc []))

(def connection-counter (new-counter))

(defn new-connection [id]
    {:id id
    :writebuf (ByteBuffer/allocate 8096)
    :readbuf (ByteBuffer/allocate 8096)})
```

Now you can use it like:

```
(new-connection (connection-counter))
```